# Orthonormalbasis of a isometry $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a bit stuck in this easy question.

Let $A\in \mathbb R^{2 \times2}$ be a isometry so $A^{-1} = \bar{A}^T$. Show that $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} b \\ d \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ is a orthonormal basis.

$A = \begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix} \Longrightarrow \bar{A}^T = \begin{pmatrix} a&c \\ b&d \end{pmatrix}$

$A \cdot \bar{A}^T = \begin{pmatrix} a^2+b^2 & ac+bd \\ ac+bd&c^2+d^2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix} $

I tried to use Gram-Schmidt but too many variables were left so I couldn't prove it.

Now i also know that is has to be

$\left\langle\begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} b \\ d \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle =0 \Longrightarrow ab+cd = 0 $ and $\left\langle\begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle =1 \Longrightarrow a^2+c^2 = 1$ but I also can't prove that because I only have $a^2+b^2 = 1 = c^2 + d^2$ and $ac+bd = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Write 
$$
v_1 = \pmatrix{a\\c} \qquad v_2 = \pmatrix{b\\d}
$$
Verify that for $A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$, we have
$$
A^TA = \pmatrix{
\langle v_1,v_1 \rangle & \langle v_2,v_1 \rangle\\
\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle & \langle v_2,v_2 \rangle}
$$

Since $A^{-1} = {A^T}$, we have ${A^T}A = I$.

Comment: Isnt that what i have done already?

Comment: @Situ actually taking a closer look, yes.  So where are you stuck?  If $A^TA = I$, then we have $\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle = \langle v_2,v_2 \rangle = 1$, while $\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle = 0$.  This tells us that $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is an orthonormal set.

Comment: Wow i am really stupid. I was sitting here around 40minutes not realizing i am already done.... Thank you

Comment: @Situ well... you did the hard part! You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $A$ is an isometry therefore $\left\|A\mathbf{x}\right\|=\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|$ for every $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$. So 
\begin{align*}
\left\| A \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\|&=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\|\\
\left\| \begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}\right\|&=\left\| \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\|\\
a^2+c^2 & =1.
\end{align*}
Likewise you can get $b^2+d^2=1$.
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Use `\| \mathbf x\|` rather than `|| \mathbf x ||` for better formatting.  Similarly, `\left\| \mathbf x \right\|`.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom your suggestion does not give the double vertical lines and that is why I had to do this.

Comment: are you saying that
$$
\left\| A \pmatrix{1\\0} \right\|
$$
is not the double vertical lines? (code: `$\left\| A \pmatrix{1\\0} \right\|$`)

Comment: Note that `|` produces a single vertical line while `\|` produces a double line.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for pointing that out. I missed the slash before |

Comment: Sorry we havent done norms yet

Comment: @Situ have you done inner (scalar) products?

Comment: @AnuragA Yes we have done that

Comment: @Situ then it is easy to translate everything I have mentioned in terms of inner products because norm and inner product can be related as $\|Ax\|^2 =\langle Ax, Ax\rangle$.